# AWS Athena Javascript SDK - Create table from query result (CTAS) - Specifiy otuput format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

I am trying using the AWS JavaScript Node.JS SDK to make a query using AWS Athena and store the results in a table in AWS Glue with Parquet format (not just a CSV file)

If I am using the conosle, it is pretty simple with a CTAS query :

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
WITH (
    external_location = 's3://bucket/tablename/',
    FORMAT = 'parquet')
    AS
SELECT *
FROM source
```

But with AWS Athena JavaScript SDK I am only able to set an output file destination using the Workgoup or Output parameters and make a basic select query, the results would output to a CSV file and would not be indexed properly in AWS Glue so it breaks a bigger process it is part of, if I try to call that query using the JavaScript SDK I get :

```
Table properties [FORMAT] are not supported.
```

I would be able to call that DDL statement using the Java SDK JDBC driver connection option.

Is anyone familiar with a solution or workaround with the Javascript SDK for Node.JS?

Comment: Show us your code, it will help figuring out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between running the SQL you posted in the Athena web console, AWS SDK for JavaScript, AWS SDK for Java, or the JDBC driver, none of these will process the SQL, so if the SQL works in one of these it will work in all of them. It's only the Athena service that reads the SQL.

Check your SQL and make sure you really use the same in your code as you have tried in the web console. If they are indeed the same, the error is somewhere else in your code, so post that too.

---

*Update* the problem is the upper case `FORMAT`. If you paste the code you posted into the Athena web console, it bugs out and doesn't run the query, but if you run it with the CLI or an SDK you get the error you posted. You did not run the same SQL in the console as in the SDK, if you had you would have gotten the same error in both.

Use lower case `format` and it will work.

This is definitely a bug in Athena, these properties should not be case sensitive.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the editor formatting upper cased my SQL to 'FORMAT' at that point the error I received - does not support FORMAT and I thought it is something with the SDK, in the AWS doc they say that only JDBC/ODBC enables CTAS queries so I thougtht they exclude direct SDK usage for those types of queries (such as Javascript) - but apperently the bug was in the capitalization ....